# Is Reservation System Suitable for Amazon DynamoDB / NoSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm working on basic restaurant reservation system and was thinking about using **Amazon DynamoDB** for this project. That being said, I'm not even sure if **DynamoDB** is suitable for something like this or if I should stick to **MySQL RDS** since some of the queries may be quite complex.

Functionality I need:

User will submit a "*Find Table*" form with date, time and party size.

1. Check `RESTAURANT` table if date and party size is even allowed.
2. Check `BLOCKED` table for blocked dates (holidays and other closures)
3. Check `HOURS` table making sure the restaurant is even open.
4. Check `TABLEINFO` table for a table based on party size `AND` compare with `RESERVATION` table making sure the table is not already reserved for another guest during the same time

Any suggestions or tips on the **DynamoDB** database design especially `hash & range` use for something like this?

Or do you think **MySQL** database is better suited for this kind of app?

This is a quick DB design to give you better idea what I'm trying to do.

[image: Reservation Schema]

Comment: I think a relational database is better suited for this type of application than a NOSQL database.  However, I recognize that that is an *opinion* and that is why I am voting to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

I've done a lot with relational databases, and a bit with NoSQL databases (just so you know where I'm coming from).  IMHO, NoSQL databases are best suited to scenarios where either one or more are true:

1. The data is essentially flat (not a lot of relations, almost like an
   old flat-file)
2. There's a definite "parent" type record with "child"
   records which are small enough/accessed frequently enough with the
   parent to justify embedding them right in the record.
3. You need the
   freedom to add/populate fields within reason.  I like to think of it
   like inheritance, where every item in the table shares some common
   traits (ID, Name), but different records might have different
   traits.  For example, an online product catalog might have books,
   bikes, and MP3 songs in it.  A record for a "book" item would have
   stuff like ISBN, number of pages, author, etc.  A "bike" might have
   wheel size and color, and an "MP3" would have length, artist, genre,
   etc.  You'd never get all of those things in an "item" table in an
   RDS without some serious overloading or leaving fields empty.  A
   NoSQL database would allow you to store all of that info in the
   table, and only for the items that need it.

You can definitely build the schema you include with your question using the indexing abilities of Dynamo, but you'd be trying to make a NoSQL database act like a RDS.

That said: I myself would try it with Dynamo first as a learning experience. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response and the valuable info. As of now, the project will be MySQL based because thats waht we already have but for in the future I was thinking about maybe having some portions of  the data stored as NoSQL. Any opinion on that? Perhaps storing user data and reservation data as NoSQL while having the relationship part as relational DB? I dont know if that make sense by I thought if I would add user info directly in the reservation table, I could store that as NoSQL as everything would be stored in that table.

Comment: DynamoDB has a lot less functionality than a relational database. It sacrifices flexibility for scaleability so is only really makes sense if you need scale. DynamoDB is designed to return from any query in under 10ms even when you have trillions of records.
When SQL based solutions just don't cut it that's when DynamoDB steps in, but you have to sacrifice functionality to get this kind of scaleability.

Comment: I agree completely. In fact, when I teach students about databases I usually warn them away from NoSQL solutions. Once you've understood WHY relational databases and normalization are necessary you can take a chance on doing without the safety net by using NoSQL.