# Restaurant table reservation schema

Tags: database-design

Hi i am creating restaurant booking application. The customer can book table with time of arrival. So i am wondering how to create the database tables in such way that it can find the free tables for the time pointed by the customer?

Comment: If this is homework, do it yourself or you won't learn. If you are genuinely in need of some database design assistance, I suggest you post an attempt at a schema and some query code and let people suggest improvements. If you have a particular SQL platform in mind, and the specific tag for that.

Comment: You might also reference this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095956/is-reservation-system-suitable-for-amazon-dynamodb-nosql

Comment: These sites might point you in a direction you need: 
1) https://my.vertabelo.com/model/gsom2MwO9H7F1MYgvYzPmOezBygXH8VV<br>
2) http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/serving-delicious-food-and-data-a-data-model-for-restaurants
http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/restaurant_bookings/restaurant_loyalty_cards.htm<br>
3) https://image.slidesharecdn.com/db201d58-01dd-4470-a94c-e2a1900e3d2f-151221124910/95/mis-6308-project-report-37-1024.jpg?cb=1450702222<br>
4) https://www.slideshare.net/ManjariRaj1/mis-6308-project-report